# In C families, in a loop why is "less than or equal to" more preferred over just "less than" symbol?

Tags: c#, c++, c

Why is it that in C family of languages when we use a counter for any loop the most preferred comparison is `Greater Equal To <=` or its inverse? Please take a look at these three pieces of code

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{...}/// loop1

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{...}/// loop2

for (var i = 0; i != 6; i++)
{...}/// loop3
```

I understand why loop 3 should be discouraged as something in code can assign `i > 5` causing infinite loop. But `loop1` and `loop2` are essentially the same and `loop2` may be better performance wise since only one comparison is done. So why is `loop1` more preferred. Is it just convention or is there something more to it?

**Note:** I have no formal training in programming. i just picked up C when I needed better tools to program 8051s rather than using assembly language.

Comment: Who said that `<=` is better?

Comment: I think you meant `!= 6` in loop 3.

Comment: @jrok If you see Code examples they are all using `<=`.

Comment: None of those examples were written by me, then :D

Comment: @AwfullyAwesome The greater than or less than.

Comment: @AwfullyAwesome I didn't someone else edited it.

Comment: BTW, personally, I do generally prefer to use equality comparisons over relational comparisons, in those cases where they both have the same effect. If `i`'s value can never be anything greater than 6, I would write the loop condition as `i != 6`. This highlights, again IMO, that I want the loop to terminate when `i == 6`. If it's not easy to see that `i`'s initial value should never be anything greater than 6, I would add an assertion to that effect.

Comment: Side note: Don´t put C/C++ together with C# as "C family". If, then Java etc. would have to be there as well.

Comment: "loop2 may be better performance wise since only one comparison is done" - says who? What CPU are you using, that doesn't have an integer `le` op?

Comment: This idiom is common to most languages that have `for` loops.

Comment: @deviantfan I think that's intentional, citing C (wrongly) as the source of the generic `for(start;condition;iterate)` idiom used by nearly all popular current programming languages.

Comment: I think the < variation is the most common, because of arrays. There is absolutely no performance difference, since the opcodes for the comparison are the same, performancewise, in modern CPUs. Asking this question is like asking why some people put the opening bracket after the function declaration while others bellow it(BTW, I hate it when people put it after the declaration. It completely messes with my 'bracket pairing' sense).

Comment: In the interests of consistency, the != form is arguably the better choice in C++. When iterating over containers for example, the iterator type may not support a < operator or the result of < may not be what you might expect. Equality is generally more efficient to test for in iterators to non-trival containers such as std:set<>. Likewise, ++i should be favoured over i++ as the latter can cause an expensive copy of the the object to be made unnecessarily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For loops are often used to iterate over arrays, and the limit is the length of the array. Since arrays are zero-based, the last valid element is `length-1`. So the choice is between:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i <= length-1; i++)
```

The first is simpler, so it is preferred. As a result, this idiom has become common even when the limit is not an array size.

We don't use `!=` because occasionally we write loops where the index increments by variable steps, and sometimes it will skip over the limit. So it's safer to use a `<` comparison, so these won't turn into infinite loops.

Comment: You didn't give `i` a type, so perhaps it's also worth pointing out that if `i` is `unsigned`, and `length` is zero, the second loop would do something completely wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Less than or equal to is *not* preferred.  Traditionally, in C,
less than was preferred; in C++, not equals is by far the most
idiomatic.  Thus, in C:

```
#define N 100

int array[N];
for ( int i = 0; i < N; i ++ ) {
    //  ...
}
```

and in C++, either:

```
int const N = 100;

int array[N];
for ( int i = 0; i != N; ++ i ) {
    //  ...
}
```

or even more often, if there is only one container, and the
index isn't needed otherwise:

```
for ( int* p = std::begin( array ); p != std::end( array ); ++ p ) {
    //  ...
}
```

(In pre-C++11, of course, we used our own implementations of
begin and end to do the same thing.)

Other forms are generally not idiomatic, and are only used in
exceptional cases.

Comment: Finally, someone addresses the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

This is generally a matter of contextual semantics, facilitating 'those that come after you' to maintain the code.

If you need 10 iterations of something, this is usually written as starting from `0` and having an end condition with `<` or `!=` because it means the `10` is literally part of the code, thus showing clearly that 10 iterations were intended. The non-inclusive notation is also more practical for zero-based arrays like C-style strings. Notation with `!=` is generally discouraged because it can cause endless loops in case the indexer isn't just a straightforward increment, unexpected overflows occur or the like.

On the other hand, if you need a loop from and to a specific value, it's also clearer if you have the end condition literally in the code, for example with `for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)` it is clear right away that it's an inclusive loop from 1 to 5.

These are just common reasons cited for using one notation or the other, most good programmers decide which to use by context and situation. There is no reason performance- or otherwise to prefer one over the other.

Comment: @SteveJessop clarified that a bit, thnx for the comment.

Comment: The notation with `!=` is by far the most common and preferred form in C=+, because it mimics the way you write loops with iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all for loops have the exact same header except for the upper bound. It is a useful convention that helps with quick understanding and making less mistakes. (And the convention is `<`, not `<=`. Not sure where you got that from.)

Programs that do the same thing are not necessarily equal when it comes to code quality. Coding style has an objective component to it in that it helps humans deal with the complexity of the task.

Consistency is an important goal. If you have the choice, prefer the alternative that the majority of team members is using.